# Can't run GolLang backend with dart and angular2 client

Tags: go, dart, angular

I use this [tutorial](http://www.sanarias.com/blog/615BuildingasimplewebappinGoDartandAngular2) to make a web application with GoLang, Angular2 and Dart, but when i start backend by console command 'backend', and route in browser to "localhost:8080/" it must call method from Dart's class "Hello" but it doesn't call, and i get 404 error. All code i got from tutorial and didn't change anything. And i can't find any other tutorials. Can you explain me what wrong am i doing?

GoLang code:

```
func main() {
   http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./app/web/")))

   fmt.Println("Text")
   http.HandleFunc("/api/hello", helloWorld)
   http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

}
func helloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   data := struct {
       Message string
   }{
       "Hello, World",
   }

   if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(data); err != nil {
       log.Println(err)
   }
}
```

and angular dart code:

```
class AppComponent {
   Hello hello = new Hello();
}

class Hello{
  String message;

  Hello(){

    HttpRequest.getString('/api/hello')
        .then((String content) {
          Map parsedMap = JSON.decode(content);
          message = parsedMap["Message"];
        })
        .catchError((Error error) {
          print(error.toString());
        });
  }
}
```

and project structure :[image]

Comment: What is "application" in "application doesn't connect to Dart side"? Why would "application" connect to "Dart side"?. If Dart is used on the client (with Angular), then the client has to connect to the server instead of the other way around.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer when i go in browser to localhost:8080/ it must call "Hello" handler which describes in web/main.dart but it doesn't do it, and just redirect to 404

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer is right.

Try to localize the issue. First check - is server side is working and responding to HTTP requests (from bwoser by entering URL to address bar, not from Dart). If it works you need to provide some information on how you call the server and what are the error logs.
Does the http://localhost:8080/api/hello works?

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok For example if i enter url "localhost:8080/api/hello" i see json response, it mean "helloWorld" handler was called, but if i go to "localhost:8080/", Dart must get it and call hello method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial is quite old. You need to switch to `HashLocationStrategy` (which was the default back then as far as I know).

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/HashLocationStrategy-class.html

Change

```
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

to

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
]);
```

You also need to add some additional imports

```
import 'package:angular2/router.dart'
    show
        HashLocationStrategy,
        LocationStrategy,
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS;
```

Comment: I added what you say, but it didn't help( Are there new tutorials for dart angular2 and go?

Comment: I haven't seen any tutorials for Angular2 and Go.